# Как подставить в CURL свою переменную из bash

Tags: linux, bash, curl

Всем привет, нужно автоматизировать заполнение заявок на 5 схожих сервисах, сделал через баш скрипт ввод необходимых значение, и как бы подставить их в тело запроса, дам небольшую вырезку

```
--data-binary $'------WebKitFormBoundary358DzhBEThSvxSfb\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="sessid"\r\n\r\nc72598fa151fe6ddaae89efe476270bb\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary358DzhBEThSvxSfb\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="Update"\r\n\r\nY\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary358DzhBEThSvxSfb\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="COPY_ID"\r\n\r\n0\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary358DzhBEThSvxSfb\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="ACTIVE"\r\n\r\nY\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary358DzhBEThSvxSfb\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="NAME"\r\n\r\nTEST_NAME\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary358DzhBEThSvxSfb\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="LAST_NAME"\r\n\r\nTEST_FAMILY\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary358DzhBEThSvxSfb\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="SECOND_NAME"\r\n\r\nTEST_PATROM\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary358DzhBEThSvxSfb\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="EMAIL"\r\n\r\nTEST_EMAIL@testmail.ru\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary358DzhBEThSvxSfb\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="LOGIN"\r\n\r\nTest\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary358DzhBEThSvxSfb\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="NEW_PASSWORD"\r\n\r\nTEST_PASS\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary358DzhBEThSvxSfb\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="NEW_PASSWORD_CONFIRM"\r\n\r\nTEST_PASS\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary358DzhBEThSvxSfb\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="LID"\r\n\r\ncp\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary358DzhBEThSvxSfb\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="GROUP_ID_0"\r\n\r\n131\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary358DzhBEThSvxSfb\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="GROUP_ID_FROM_0"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary358DzhBEThSvxSfb\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="GROUP_ID_TO_0"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary358DzhBEThSvxSfb\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name="GROUP_ID_1"\r\n\r\n130\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary358DzhBE
```

Хочу обратить внимание на

```
name="NAME"\r\n\r\nTEST_NAME\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary358DzhBEThSvxSfb`\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
```

Если указываю TEST_NAME, то все работает идеально, если подставляю переменную $User_Name, с таким же значением, то она просто не работает, это понятно, потому что запрос в одинарных кавычках, если написать:

```
name="NAME"\r\n\r\n'$User_Name'\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary358DzhBEThSvxSfb`\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
```

То все что после, отрежется, и вставится только это поле.

Как это исправить?

Comment: `--data-binary $'` — а зачем здесь знак доллара?

Comment: он тут был когда копировал curl

Comment: ну, допустим. тогда и вторую часть строки тоже имеет смысл записать именно в такой форме. чтобы получилось: `--data-binary $'...'$User_Name$'...'`

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное) выручили очень

Answer (score 1):

в параметре, передаваемом программе *curl*, используется специальный синтаксис для строки: `$'строка'`. он поддерживается в популярных оболочках (например, *bash* и *zsh*), но, насколько я знаю, не входит в стандарт *posix*.

внутри такой строки происходит подмена строк типа `\n` на символы. например, строка `\n` преобразуется в символ перевода строки, имеющий шестнадцатиричное значение `0a`).

---

покажу на примере, что у вас «пошло не так».

пусть у нас имеется строка, содержащая `\n`. при её интерпретации оболочкой происходят преобразования:

```
$ echo $'a\nb\nc'
a
b
c
```

если же не использовать этот синтаксис, то преобразований не происходит:

```
$ echo 'a\nb\nc'
a\nb\nc
```

разорвав строку на две части и подставив вместо, например, символа `b` вывод переменной, мы получим:

```
$ var=zzz; echo $'a\n'$var'\nc'
a
zzz\nc
```

т.е., во второй части (`'\nc'`) не было произведено описанных преобразований. чтобы они произошли и там, вторую часть тоже надо записать, используя тот же специальный синтаксис (`$'\nc'`):

```
$ var=zzz; echo $'a\n'$var$'\nc'
a
zzz
c
```